# WP contact form 7 "textarea" looks different from other fields

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web, contacts

Hey I've been stuck on this for a while now cant seem to fix it I'm sure its something simple that I'm missing!

I'm editing my site in WP with the Meetup theme and in the "Nomination" section all the fields look alike except for the "textarea" does anyone know how to fix this??

WEBSITE - http://www.tedxtlvu.com/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No CSS defined for textarea, Add this in your custom style css

```
div.wpcf7 textarea {
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    background: rgba(200,200,200,0.3);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 12px;
    padding-left: 24px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

change `<div class="col-sm-6">` to `<div class="col-sm-12">` if you want textarea to cover the full width.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding textarea in the the following code:

You just need to add textarea in the css property where the previous code was -

```
input[type="text"], input[type="email"], input[type="tel"], .register .select-holder{
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  background: rgba(200,200,200,0.3);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  max-width: 90%;
  padding: 12px;
  padding-left: 24px;
}
```

So after changes the code will be

```
textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="email"], input[type="tel"], .register .select-holder{
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  background: rgba(200,200,200,0.3);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  max-width: 90%;
  padding: 12px;
  padding-left: 24px;
}
```

Results

[image]